# Set model date defaultValue to string

Tags: date, ember.js, default-value

I try to build a 'task manager' to log the tasks that my customers send me.

I have my new-task.hbs form

```
<div id="new-task-form" class="col-md-12">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer</label>
        {{input type="text" class="form-control" value=customer placeholder="Add Customer..."}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Task</label>
        {{textarea class="form-control" value=task placeholder="Add Task..."}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Incoming</label>
        {{input type="number" class="form-control" value=incoming placeholder="Bring it on..."}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Pending</label>
        {{input type="number" class="form-control" value=pending placeholder="Don't bring it on..."}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Closed Date</label>
        {{input type="date" class="form-control" value=closed_date placeholder="Please close me..."}}
    </div>

    <button {{action 'addTask'}} class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

My controller.

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        addTask: function(){
            var customer = this.get('customer');
            var task = this.get('task');
            var incoming = this.get('incoming');
            var pending = this.get('pending');
            var closed_date = this.get('closed_date');
            //Create new task
            var newTask = this.store.createRecord('task',{
                customer: customer,
                task: task,
                incoming: incoming,
                pending: pending,
                closed_date: closed_date
            });
            //save to db
            newTask.save();
        }
    }
});
```

And the model

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
  customer: attr('string'),
  task: attr('string'),
  incoming: attr('number', { defaultValue: 0 }),
  pending: attr('number', { defaultValue: 0 }),
  closed_date: attr('date'),
  created: attr('string', {
    defaultValue: function(){
        return new Date();
    }
  })  
});
```

How can i set a model defaultValue for a the closed_date input to a string "Not entered yet"?

If i leave it like this and not enter a value i get an "Invalid Date".

```
closed_date: attr('date')
```

If i set this i get the current date.

```
closed_date: attr('date', { defaultValue: 'Not entered yet' })
```

Comment: You are getting "Invalid Date" error because you are passing a string when creating a new task: `closed_date: 'closed_date'`

Comment: I was doing some tests and I forgot to remove the quotes on the copy paste. The result is the same without them.

Comment: You could set your date as "string" attribute and handle it in the backend side.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience I suggest you leave `closed_date` as it is (as date) and focus on DISPLAYING `Not entered yet` in each place that you want to show it when `closed_date` isn't entered.

For example when you show model values in template you can use:

```
Closed date: {{if model.closed_date model.closed_date 'Not entered yet'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [ember-pikaday](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday) for a nice date-selection experience (which also gives you the placeholder functionality you are looking for!).

Furthermore, I'd suggest that you use the model hook of your new-task route to do your model setup. Combine that with [ember-data-route](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-data-route) to do cleanup on route exit, and you should be good to go:

`router.js`:

```
this.route('tasks', function() {
  this.route('new');
});
```

`routes/tasks/new.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DataRoute from 'ember-data-route';

export default Route.extend(DataRoute, {
  model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('task');
  }
});
```

- Note below how the form field values have been updated to `model.fieldName`. These values are bound to the model you created in your route's model hook.

`templates/tasks/new.hbs`:

```
<div id="new-task-form" class="col-md-12">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer</label>
        {{input type="text" class="form-control" value=model.customer placeholder="Add Customer..."}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Task</label>
        {{textarea class="form-control" value=model.task placeholder="Add Task..."}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Incoming</label>
        {{input type="number" class="form-control" value=model.incoming placeholder="Bring it on..."}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Pending</label>
        {{input type="number" class="form-control" value=model.pending placeholder="Don't bring it on..."}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            Closed Date:
            {{pikaday-input value=model.closedDate placeholder="Please close me..."}}
        </label>
    </div>

    <button {{action 'addTask'}} class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

- Note: prefer camelCasedMultipleWordModelAttributeName vs underscored_attribute_name

`models/task.js`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
  customer: attr('string'),
  task: attr('string'),
  incoming: attr('number', { defaultValue: 0 }),
  pending: attr('number', { defaultValue: 0 }),
  closedDate: attr('date', {
    defaultValue() { return new Date(); }
  }),
  created: attr('string', {
    defaultValue() { return new Date(); }
  })  
});
```

Now the nice part. Here's what your controller action looks like when you do your setup in your route's model hook:

`controllers/tasks/new.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    addTask: function(){
      this.get('model').save();
    }
  }
});
```

and for extra credit you could install [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) and move the controller action onto the route and remove the controller completely.